# How to disable effects of other power up if picked a new power ups?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where you can pick up a power up and gives you a boost or a new perks Ex. The fire power up makes you jump higher and makes your character/ball small and when you pick up the other power ups makes a new different perks or power

BTW I'm new at C# and unity my Idea is not to have a timer for each power ups but when you pick up a new power up it disables the effect of the last power up you picked up. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing any code. Have you tried to set the property [enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) to `false` on the components that you want to disable?

Comment: I've added the printscreen of the code on my post sir.

Comment: Please, don't post a picture of your code; edit the question to include the relevant code (check [mcve])

Comment: Also, how are you planning to use your `Powers` script? Will you have lots of scripts, each representing a kind of power, or will you have 1 Power class that will manage the state and change the effect depending on it?

Comment: 1 script for each power ups with different effects. I just need to turn off or change the effects of the other script that I have picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should build an own class or system to handle your powerup mechanic. The code would be really just the manifestation of your logic. If it works with enabling and disabling scripts, then write a manager class which does exactly that. Reference each script in the inspector. When the player collects something, disable all of the scripts and enable the desired target script. Make use of enums.

But there are certainly better/other ways to handle that than having one script for each mechanic. Things get quickly out of control and quite messy if you do that. I bet 90%+ of the effects can be performed by just playing around with numbers (scaling, movement speed, jump height, etc), so what if you create a class whose instances embody floats to take care of that? For example the one you described would be:

```
public class Powerup
{
    SpecialEffect SpecialE = SpecialEffect.Shrink; // (enum)
    float SizeMod = 0.4f;
    float JumpMod = 2.0f;
    float SpeedMod = 1.0f; // (changes nothing)
    float DamageMod = 1.0f; // (changes nothing)

    public void ApplyEffects ()
    {
        // Do the changes to the player.
    }
}
```

You can expose a list of these Powerups to the inspector and fill in your elements, or do it via code in form of an initiate (I do these things with many excel sheets which get parsed, allowing me to write my data properly while having a great overwiew).